# Why do javascript literals act differently as their non-literal counterparts?

Tags: javascript, variables, literals

It's something I've always taken for granted, but would like to know the reasoning of.

For example, why can I do:

```
var a = new Number(1);
a.test = 'string';
console.log(a.test);
>>> 'string'
```

But when I do

```
var a = 1;
a.test = 'string';
console.log(a.test)
>>> undefined
```

Why do they act so differently?

Edit: Andrea phrased the question much better than I could over in this thread: [Javascript primitive types and corresponding objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183009/javascript-primitive-types-and-corresponding-objects)

Comment: I don't know what to say... I can't understand why you would expect these to be same at all

Comment: Even though it doesn't cause an Error you can't add properties on JavaScript primitive types. Since a is a primitive type the "added" property doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

> If JavaScript detects an attempt to assign a property to a primitive it will indeed coerce the primitive to an object.

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/