# Any good reasons to use the Number constructor (as opposed to literals)?

Tags: javascript, constructor, literals

Are there any good reasons to use `new Number(n)`? Why does this constructor exist?

I can think of several reasons to avoid it, eg.,

- literals are more memory efficient since they don't construct anything new.
- literals are equal to each other (`5 === 5` but `new Number(5) !== new Number(5)`).
- the `typeof` operator indicates that it's a number rather than an object.
- `new Number(0)` is never falsey. (`!!new Number(false) == true`).
- You can use it for type conversion, but there are more concise methods. (`+false === 0`).

To be clear, I understand the Number object has useful methods and properties, my question is specifically about the *constructor*.

I'm using Number as an example, but I don't understand why Javascript exposes other constructors where literals are available either (String, Object, Array, etc.).

Why do these exist and are there ever any good reason to use them?

Comment: The Number constructor is called implicitly in cases like `(1.234).toFixed(1)` (which is nonsensical). The semantics of the language require object "partner" types for the primitive types. In practical terms, explicit deliberate use of Number objects in real code is what I would consider a terrible design decision, and is probably extremely rare.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988751/841830   I used `Number(s)`, in preference to `parseFloat()`, for this very reason the other day.    (Also note the difference between `new Number(s)` and `Number(s)` )

Comment: @deceze - The threads you posted are not duplicates. They are relevant but I already know that stuff and stated that in my question. Please reopen the question unless you can find one that answer the questions ***Why do the constructors exist, and is there any reason to use them***. This is not a duplicate. I searched for three days before asking.

Comment: @DarrenCook - I get that. I stated that in my question. ***my question is specifically about the constructor.***

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052367/476

Comment: @deceze - That would be a relevant answer here, but it is mostly opinion based. A relevant answer on another thread is no the same as a duplicate question.

Comment: You would need to ask [Brendan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) himself for the reason why they exist. And even then, you'd only get *his opinion*. The fact is they do exist, you know how they behave, there's ample discussion why you shouldn't use them. What would be a possible reason to *hide* those types? As it is, something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(foo)` is a common idiom, only possible because the type and its prototype is exposed. It would seem even weirder if you needed to create an instance using a literal first to access those prototype functions.

Comment: Thank you @deceze. That pretty much answers my questions. It doesn't explain why you erroneously marked my question as a dupe though. I would have liked to hear from other people on the subject.